# Executing external file as www-data (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, permissions, www-data

I want to start a virtual machine through PHP, but i've had no luck.  Here's what i've got.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_start'])){
  echo shell_exec('whoami');
  echo exec('virsh start winagain');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Manage VPS</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="vps.php">
  <input type="submit" name="btn_start" value="Start">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error:

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: no valid connection
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission denied
```

So i tried putting this line into my /etc/sudoers file

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
```

But it has done nothing.

I'm running out of ideas now, please help.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault.  Be sure to take the tour to see how this works and to earn a badge:  https://serverfault.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use sudo (which you probably do) to elevate privileges you need to :

- grant access to the `virsh` command and not the socket file
- use the absolute path to the `virsh` command in `/etc/sudoers` i.e.
  `www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/virsh`
- need to call `sudo` in your exec command
- need to use the absolute path to `virsh` with sudo in your exec command i.e.
  `shell_exec("/bin/sudo /path/to/virsh start wine again")`

Comment: Thank you, I had made a temp fix with chmod -R 777 but i know that's not exactly safe... You're a life saver!